# Android 4.4.4 Moto G Bluetooth LE reconnect issue

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, motorola

I have an app that works great on a Samsung S3 running Android 4.3 however i've having issues on a Moto G running 4.4.4

My BLE peripheral connects and disconnects several times during the apps use. This works fine however sometimes there comes a point where the app/phone no longer reconnects to the peripheral.

All gatt commands are run on the main thread, eg.

```
final BluetoothGatt gat = gatt;
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.post(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
  // This code will be executed on the main thread
  if (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) {
    Log.e(TAG, "mGattCallback disconnect2: NOW ON MAIN THREAD :)");
  }
  gat.disconnect();
  }
});
```

and the peripheral disconnects fine. When this happens and I can't reconnect to the peripheral any more, I get loads of log's like this:

```
04-07 16:57:56.798: I/bt-hci(2127): BLE HCI(id=62) event = 0x02)
04-07 16:57:56.798: I/bt-hci(2127): btu_ble_process_adv_pkt
04-07 16:57:56.833: I/bt-hci(2127): BLE HCI(id=62) event = 0x02)
04-07 16:57:56.833: I/bt-hci(2127): btu_ble_process_adv_pkt
04-07 16:57:56.871: I/bt-hci(2127): BLE HCI(id=62) event = 0x02)
04-07 16:57:56.871: I/bt-hci(2127): btu_ble_process_adv_pkt
04-07 16:57:56.906: I/bt-hci(2127): BLE HCI(id=62) event = 0x02)
04-07 16:57:56.906: I/bt-hci(2127): btu_ble_process_adv_pkt
04-07 16:57:56.941: I/bt-hci(2127): BLE HCI(id=62) event = 0x02)
04-07 16:57:56.941: I/bt-hci(2127): btu_ble_process_adv_pkt
04-07 16:57:56.977: I/bt-hci(2127): BLE HCI(id=62) event = 0x02)
04-07 16:57:56.977: I/bt-hci(2127): btu_ble_process_adv_pkt
04-07 16:57:57.016: I/bt-hci(2127): BLE HCI(id=62) event = 0x02)
04-07 16:57:57.016: I/bt-hci(2127): btu_ble_process_adv_pkt
```

and I need to quit the app, turn bluetooth off and on again for it to start working properly again.

Any known issues, tips or advice?

Thanks

EDIT -----------
After some more testing, it seems that leaving the app running, eventually I get the following logs and then my peripheral can reconnect again:

```
04-13 19:11:53.973: I/bt-hci(2034): BLE HCI(id=62) event = 0x02)
04-13 19:11:53.973: I/bt-hci(2034): btu_ble_process_adv_pkt
04-13 19:11:54.076: I/bt-hci(2034): BLE HCI(id=62) event = 0x02)
04-13 19:11:54.076: I/bt-hci(2034): btu_ble_process_adv_pkt
04-13 19:11:55.986: I/bt-hci(2034): BLE HCI(id=62) event = 0x02)
04-13 19:11:55.986: I/bt-hci(2034): btu_ble_process_adv_pkt
04-13 19:11:56.087: I/bt-hci(2034): BLE HCI(id=62) event = 0x02)
04-13 19:11:56.087: I/bt-hci(2034): btu_ble_process_adv_pkt
04-13 19:11:56.629: I/bt-hci(2034): BLE HCI(id=62) event = 0x02)
04-13 19:11:56.629: I/bt-hci(2034): btu_ble_process_adv_pkt
04-13 19:11:56.734: I/bt-hci(2034): BLE HCI(id=62) event = 0x02)
04-13 19:11:56.734: I/bt-hci(2034): btu_ble_process_adv_pkt
04-13 19:11:58.925: D/MDMCTBK(275): reply_len: 40 reply is = IFNAME=wlan0 <3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS 
04-13 19:11:58.925: D/MDMCTBK(275): Event received = CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS 
04-13 19:11:58.926: D/WifiStateMachine(1010): handleMessage: E msg.what=147461
04-13 19:11:58.926: D/WifiStateMachine(1010): processMsg: DisconnectedState
04-13 19:11:58.926: D/WifiStateMachine(1010): processMsg: ConnectModeState
04-13 19:11:58.926: D/WifiStateMachine(1010): processMsg: DriverStartedState
04-13 19:11:58.927: D/WifiStateMachine(1010): processMsg: SupplicantStartedState
04-13 19:11:58.928: D/TCMD(4253): NL - Read 56 bytes from update socket.
04-13 19:11:58.928: D/TCMD(4253): NL - message type is RTM_NEWLINK
04-13 19:11:58.928: D/TCMD(4253): Listening for incoming client connection request
04-13 19:35:18.787: V/AlarmManager(1010): sending alarm Alarm{42b84cc0 type 2 com.google.android.gms}
04-13 19:35:18.787: V/AlarmManager(1010): sending alarm Alarm{42b83a00 type 0 android}
04-13 19:11:58.941: D/WifiStateMachine(1010): handleMessage: X
04-13 19:12:00.615: D/WifiStateMachine(1010): handleMessage: E msg.what=131143
04-13 19:12:00.615: D/WifiStateMachine(1010): processMsg: DisconnectedState
04-13 19:12:00.616: D/WifiStateMachine(1010): processMsg: ConnectModeState
04-13 19:12:00.617: D/WifiStateMachine(1010): processMsg: DriverStartedState
04-13 19:12:00.628: D/WifiStateMachine(1010): handleMessage: X
04-13 19:12:01.425: D/MDMCTBK(275): reply_len: 40 reply is = IFNAME=wlan0 <3>CTRL-EVENT-BSS-REMOVED 1
04-13 19:12:01.425: D/MDMCTBK(275): Event received = CTRL-EVENT-BSS-REMOVED 1
04-13 19:12:01.425: D/MDMCTBK(275): reply_len: 40 reply is = IFNAME=wlan0 <3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS 
04-13 19:12:01.425: D/MDMCTBK(275): Event received = CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS 
04-13 19:12:01.425: D/WifiStateMachine(1010): handleMessage: E msg.what=147461
04-13 19:12:01.426: D/WifiStateMachine(1010): processMsg: DisconnectedState
04-13 19:12:01.426: D/WifiStateMachine(1010): processMsg: ConnectModeState
04-13 19:12:01.426: D/WifiStateMachine(1010): processMsg: DriverStartedState
04-13 19:12:01.426: D/WifiStateMachine(1010): processMsg: SupplicantStartedState
04-13 19:12:01.428: D/MDMCTBK(275): reply_len: 40 reply is = IFNAME=p2p0 <3>CTRL-EVENT-BSS-REMOVED 1 
04-13 19:12:01.428: D/MDMCTBK(275): Event received = CTRL-EVENT-BSS-REMOVED 1 
04-13 19:12:01.428: D/TCMD(4253): NL - Read 56 bytes from update socket.
04-13 19:12:01.428: D/TCMD(4253): NL - message type is RTM_NEWLINK
04-13 19:12:01.428: D/TCMD(4253): Listening for incoming client connection request
04-13 19:12:01.444: D/WifiStateMachine(1010): handleMessage: X
```

It's looking like it's something to do with the WiFi?!

Comment: in your code, you disconnect your gat out of if() condition. May be is this ?

Comment: I'll have a check, but the code is set to run in a MainLooper, so it should always be true.

Comment: Gatt disconnect is always called, so that's not the problem. I've added an edit to my question above. Thx

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm currently struggling with the Moto G first gen and second gen with 5.0 and 5.1 respectively.

Comment: No, we just don't support that device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there will not be an easy answer like "use Main Thread" and everything is OK. But I can give you some hints I gathered while working with crappy Android BLE:

- BT stack will be different on different phones, unfortunately Moto G is one of most crappiest phones if we're talking about BLE... how crappy? Tile app even states in their [F.A.Q What Android phones will Tile work with](https://www.thetileapp.com/android):

> will work only with Samsung Galaxy S5, HTC One M8, HTC One, LG Nexus 4, LG Nexus 5, LG Nexus 6, Samsung Note 4, Motorola Moto X **and certainly will not work with Moto G**

- try to aim in Android 5.0 and above, this official video from google says so https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=2fZThdNbHcQ#t=0 and furthermore in here [Android Lollipop: Bluetooth LE Matures](https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/1697/android_lollipop_bluetooth_andevcon) you can find

> ```
> Bluedroid continues to mature and stabilize; there were 565 commits to the bluedroid project alone from 4.4 -> 5.0, compared with 52 commits from 4.3 -> 4.4, and 47 commits from 4.2 -> 4.3.* This is an area of heavy activity within AOSP right now.
> ```

- there's also [maximum number of connections (7) in Android 4.4 and further](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=qx55Sa8UZAQ#t=0) - look around 31'st minute

Answer (score 2):

This is a MotoG specific problem, i have encountered the same on MotoG devices previously.  From when Bluetooth Low Energy was not mature enough, the Wifi and Bluetooth functionality, adversely, interferes each other on that particular device.

From the previous R&D i had done, not sure whether this is an OS version & device specific combination but
there have been some issues related to Bluetooth and Wifi, even more with Bluetooth Low Energy and Wifi, many have been device specific.

Regarding what you are facing, there are issues on *Android Open Source Project - Issue Tracker* and other blogs also;

[Issue 39995](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39995)
[Issue 41631](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41631)

[Nexus 5, Nexus 4 and Nexus 7 (2013) Android 4.4 Bluetooth Issues](http://au.ibtimes.com/articles/533189/20140107/nexus-5-7-android-4-kitkat.htm#.U8dp_vmSwrE)
[Although i haven't faced that issue in Nexus 5]

Irrespective of number of connections, the Wifi affects bluetooth low energy. Also, the reconnection and timeout for a connection can be properties from the hardware side too.

Your code is fine, hope you save some time, i have spent some time on that with MotoG and a few other devices; precisely the case of bluetooth low energy and wifi interference while interacting with ble-devices, through BluetoothGatt and iBeacon framework.